# Arrange elements truely randomly by row

Tags: r, random

I want to randomly arrange the elements in my data frame by rows. However, at the moment the arrangement is not really random because the elements of `x2` and `x3` can only appear at positions 1:18 and 19:36 respectively. How can I change my code so that the elements can show up at any position?

```
# Parameter
n_row <- 6
n_col <- 6
pch <- 1:11
col <- 1:8

# Randomly arrange elements by row
x1 <- setNames(expand.grid(pch, col), c("pch", "col"))
x2 <- x1[sample(seq_len(nrow(x1)), n_row*n_col*.5), ]
x3 <- x2[sample(1:nrow(x2)), ]
final <- sample(rbind(x2, x3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try `sample`ing the `rep`eated `sample`.

```
set.seed(42)
res <- x1[sample(rep(sample(seq_len(nrow(x1)), 6*6*.5), 2)), ]
```

Check the result using `table`

```
table(res)
#     col
# pch  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#   1  0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
#   2  0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
#   3  2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0
#   4  0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0
#   5  2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0
#   7  0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
#   8  0 0 0 2 0 0 2 0
#   9  0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
#   10 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0
#   11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
```

or if they `all` are either `0` or `2`.

```
all(table(res) %in% c(0, 2))
# [1] TRUE
```

---

*Data:*

```
x1 <- expand.grid(pch=1:11, col=1:8)
```